# How to handle unsupported statement value and Value cannot be null errors in visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two messages in error list:

- Message       Unsupported statement value: Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.CodeDom.CodeBodyTextStatement. 0
- Message       Value cannot be null. Parameter name: format     0

It makes me unable to use Visual Studio designer.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;



namespace TestSQL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(GetButton1());
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool exception = false;

            string ID, name;  
            float age;
            
                ID = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                name = textBox2.Text.ToString();
                if(!float.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out age))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Input error");
                    exception = true;
                }
                if (!exception)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection([SQL string here]);
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"Insert into Table values (@id,@name,@age)", connect);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to change parsing code, because VS sugested me to do so. I have updated and repaired whole Visual Studio and it's still not working.

Comment: What is this: `InitializeComponent(GetButton1());`? Remove that `GetButton1()` thing

Comment: @Jimi It's a thing that Visual Studio made. Deleting it makes it unable to even debug and run, and throws new error in designer: The designer cannot process the code at line 17: throw new NotImplementedException(); The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.

Comment: I didn't say *delete the whole thing*, I said remove `GetButton1()` -- You're saying that VS added `GetButton1()` to the `InitializeComponent()` call, which has no parameters by default? If **you** added an overload to `InitializeComponent()`, remove that, too. Just call the standard, parameter-less, one

Comment: @Jimi yup I deleted only GetButton1(). When InitializeComponent() have no parameter then it has an underline and it suggest me to make code like this:

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Comment: Did you by any chance delete the `designer.cs` file?

Comment: Then you have tampered with the `.Designer.cs` file of your Form, modifying the standard `InitializeComponent()` method. Remove any edits you have introduced. There are comments in that file that warn against it -- This assuming you have used the default Form Template to build your Form. If that's not the case, then describe what you have actually done

Comment: @Jimi oh god there were some random button parameter added in here, you're right. Now it's working, thank you so much. I think I have used this Visual Studio repair suggestions so it added this. Thanks.